# Getting json data from an API, how to show the data in a loop in table format or bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, json, api

Iam getting a json data from an API in the following format:

```
{"total":254,
 "countries":[  
 {  
  "name":"Zimbabwe",
  "code3":"ZWE",
  "code":"ZW"
 },
 {  
  "name":"Zambia",
  "code3":"ZMB",
  "code":"ZM"
  },
  {  
  "name":"Yemen",
  "code3":"YEM",
  "code":"YE"
  },
  {  
  "name":"XO",
  "code3":"XO ",
  "code":"XO"
  }
  }
```

This is my PHP Script to access the API data:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'api-key: 1234',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));     
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.com/api/v3/countries');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$xml = curl_exec ($curl);  

if ($xml === false) {
    die('Error fetching data: ' . curl_error($curl));  
}
curl_close ($curl);  
echo htmlspecialchars("$xml", ENT_QUOTES);   
?>
```

How will i call the results in a table format or bootstrap format?

Comment: That data you receive is not in xml format, as your variable name seems to suggest, but in json format, just as you explicitly request in the http headers you sent. That means you have to `json_decode()` it first, then you can iterate over the `countries` array in  a simple  loop.

Comment: Something like this..? $json_a = json_decode($xml, true);

    foreach ($json_a as $country => $countries) {
        echo $countries['name'];
    }

Comment: Iam getting an error after putting the above code: Notice: Undefined index: name

Comment: Can anyone pls help me on this.

Comment: Actually the json you posted is invalid... Are you sure that is exactly what you receive?

Comment: Its a very long json data: Iam receiving the raw data in this format:"{"total":254,"countries":[{"name":"Zimbabwe","code3":"ZWE","code":"ZW"},{"name":"Zambia","code3":"ZMB","code":"ZM"},{"name":"Yemen","code3":"YEM","code":"YE"}

Comment: Ah, so you truncated it. You should have marked that in your question... Anyway, you need something like that: `$data->countries[1]['name']`, where `1` obviously is an example for the index of the entry you want to access in your loop.

Comment: I am not getting. still let me try. Thank you.

Comment: and what if i need to access all the data. Can i do it in a foreach loop?

Comment: `$data = json_decode($json); foreach ($data->countries as $country) { echo $country['name']; }`

Comment: Iam getting error when i added the code: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. This line is having the error, echo $country['name'];

Comment: I Do apologize, I blindly copied your snippet... `$data = json_decode($json); foreach ($data->countries as $country) { echo $country->name; }`

Comment: Thank you so much. its working very well now. :)